# Query posts by category AND meta value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

Okay, so I'm trying to get this resolved. My issue comes down to querying posts by meta value and category, and I can't seem to get it to output anything.

I've done the `WP_Query();` route, and dumped my variables, and the form is returning everything it should in those variables, but it isn't pulling any posts from the database. I'm getting no results. Code below.

```
<h1>Product Selector</h1>
        <?php 
        if ( !$_POST['submit'] ) : ?>
            <form method="post">
                <br><strong>Category:</strong><br>
                <?php wp_dropdown_categories(array(
                    'show_option_all' => 'Please Choose',
                )); ?>
                <br><br><strong>Adhesion:</strong><br>
                    <select id="adhesion" name="adhesion">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>
                <!--<br><br><strong>Substrate:</strong><br>
                    <select id="substrate" name="substrate">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>-->
                <br><br>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
        <?php 
        else : 
            $ca = $_POST['cat'];
            $ad =  array( 'key' => 'adhesion_box', 'value' => $_POST['adhesion'] );
            $su = array( 'key' => 'substrate_box', 'value' => $_POST['substrate'] );

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'meta_query' => array($ad),
                'cat' => $ca,
            );

            var_dump($args);

        $myQuery = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

            <?php 
            if ( $myQuery->have_posts() ) :
                echo "<ul>";
                while ($myQuery->have_posts()) : 
                $myQuery->the_post(); ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile;
                echo "</ul>";

            else : ?>
                <h3>Sorry, no products matched the details you entered.</h3>
                <form method="post">
                    <br><br><strong>Category:</strong><br>
                    <?php wp_dropdown_categories(array(
                        'show_option_all' => 'Please Choose',
                    )); ?>
                <br><br><strong>Adhesion:</strong><br>
                    <select id="adhesion" name="adhesion">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>
                <!--<br><br><strong>Substrate:</strong><br>
                    <select id="substrate" name="substrate">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>
                <br><br>-->


                    <br><br>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                </form>
            <?php 
            endif;

        endif; ?>
```

And no, it isn't calling for a category template or anything like that because I don't include that call in my loop, and WordPress only calls for template files when you make it do so. High five.

I use custom loops on other pages like this, but some reason, this one just doesn't freaking return any posts and I can't figure it out.

Go into the products, and find a specific product, any one you want, and then enter its specs into the form (so you KNOW you have a specific product that should return) and watch as... nothing happens....

What is wrong with my query? I can't figure this out.

### Relevant Link

http://carotape.bigwolfdesigns.com/product-selector/

Comment: how are u accessing these values on server side? try printing $_REQUEST and check

Comment: @Remy Sheppard Can you tell adhesion is serialize object or integer? Is it possible for you to post some sample data with structure

Comment: This question is misleading because the OP is looking for a query which retrieves the `meta_value` from the database, and he's asking the community for something else: `current query isn't returning any result`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is posting properly, here's the POST data:

[image]

My guess would be something on the PHP end that is causing issues.

Can you post code of how you're handling the POST data?

EDIT:

I think I see the issue, you're setting the array twice.  You instantiate an array for $ad, but then in $args you do it again.

This should work:

```
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array($ad),
        'cat' => $ca,
        );
```

More on multidimensional arrays:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Also, you need to think about how WP_Query is handling your args.  $ad is an array, and I'm unsure as to how it would handle that (not experienced in WP).  It's possible that the function is returning null because you're passing in a array to it and it really wants a string.

I would start by turning on debugging, and var_dump $args, and if that checks out, check the return status on the query.

Answer (score 2):

try the following code. You are using $ad as string which is and array so it will be assigned as  string "Array" and that key will be searched

```
   $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'meta_query' => array($ad),
       'cat' => $ca,
   );
```

Comment: It says that no products match my description, when I know for a fact there is at least one product that does.

Comment: This was not the answer. I've updated to include the entire code for the page.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a combination of things.

Firstly, the most efficient way to grab the data is through `get_posts();`, the code for that looks as follows:

```
$ca = $_POST['cat'];
$ad =  $_POST['adhesion'];

$args = array(
    'category' => $ca,
    'meta_key' => 'adhesion_box',
    'meta_value' => $ad,
);


$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; 

wp_reset_postdata();
```

The next problem I uncovered by using `var_dump();`. I realized that the adhesion option select wasn't returning the right value. The problem there was in my AJAX call, this line:

```
for (var k in data) {
    var option = $('<option />').val(k).html(data[k]);
```

Needed to be:
    for (var k in data) {
        var option = $('').val(data[k]).html(data[k]);

My php script was trying to query the database for the key, and not the data value in the array.

Everything works now.

Thanks to @jorblume for telling me to `var_dump()` my array.

Answer (score -1):

There's 2 different ways of doing that:

Method 1:

```
<?php
$category = isset($_POST['cat']) ? $_POST['cat'] : '';
$adhesion = isset($_POST['adhesion']) ? $_POST['adhesion'] : '';
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category' => $category,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'adhesion_box',
            'value' => $adhesion,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);
$queryObject = new WP_Query($query);
?>
```

Method 2:

```
<?php
$category = isset($_POST['cat']) ? $_POST['cat'] : '';
$adhesion = isset($_POST['adhesion']) ? $_POST['adhesion'] : '';
$query_str = "  SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
                FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->post2cat ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->post2cat.post_id)
                WHERE 
                    $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
                AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
                AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'adhesion'
                AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = %s
                AND $wpdb->post2cat.category_id = %s
            ";
$query = $wpdb->prepare($query_str, array($adhesion, $category));
$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
?>
```

For more info, check these 2 links:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query

Comment: You didn't mention that you want to retrieve the meta_value using a query. Here's you're code `$ad =  array( 'key' => 'adhesion_box', 'value' => $_POST['adhesion'] );`. You're filling the `value` manually. You only mentioned that the query you wrote isn't returning any data. I just fixed your query.

Comment: On another hand, if you already found the answer, then you should close this question and mark the valid answer, and you should consider closing the bounty too. Keeping this question open isn't helping anyone.